# How to resolve dependency injection with COM Interop (Excel)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, com-interop

I would like to add dependency injection with COM interop (Excel) object. I'm wondering if it doesn't fail because of the `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` declaration in both main program and class library. I'm also a bit concern about dependency injection, because I also have to reference Excel in the main program.

Main program (oversimplified)

```
class Program
{
    private static ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Setups dependency injection
        var service = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<ExcelConnector>()
            .AddSingleton<Excel.Application>(provider =>
                new Excel.Application
                {
                    DisplayAlerts = false,
                    Visible = false
                }
            )
            .AddSingleton<Program>();
        
        _serviceProvider = service.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        using var excel = _serviceProvider.GetService<ExcelConnector>();
    }
}
```

Class library

```
public class ExcelConnector : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Excel.Application _xlApp;
    
    public ExcelConnector(Excel.Application xlApp)
    {
        _xlApp = xlApp
    }
    
    #region IDisposable Implementation
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Cleans up
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        
        if (_xlApp != null)
        {
            _xlApp.Quit();
            _ = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlApp);
        }
    }
    
    #endregion
}
```

I get the following error:
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' while attempting to activate 'MacrosLibrary.ExcelConnector'.'**

Am I missing something? Would an interface help cope with this issue?

Thanks for any insights.

**UPDATE AND PRECISIONS**

It is a .NET Framework 4.8 project which the C# 8.0 update (`using var`).

It is a new program with perfectly work it I remove the `Excel.Application xlApp` constructor arguments and new the `_xlApp` up.

I don't think that the library versions differ (I've always read that it is not possible to install 2 different Office versions on the same computer..). It is Excel 16.0 64-bits. The library is located here : *C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll*.

I've already had to change something in the `Embed Interop Types`, but believe in was in a C++ project. It was set to true, changing it to false resolve the issue...

Comment: Hmmm, may be the program and the library use different versions of the interop library?

Comment: Do you have 'Embed Interop Types' set for any Office assembly project references? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/samng/the-pain-of-deploying-primary-interop-assemblies

Comment: OK, thanks. I added information on my question. Setting the 'Embed Interop Types' to false solves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I set 'Embed Interop Types' to false, there seems to be a cast issue. For example, I can't write `xlRange[1, 1].Value` anymore if `_xlRange` is an `Excel.Range` object.. By the way, I don't either get intelli-sense with 'Embed Interop Types' to true. I won't probably use dependency injection in this case because I don't really want to expose the COM library outside of the class library.

Comment: You definitely want to have 'Embed Interop Types' set to true if you can't control what version of Office you're working against.